# how to get value in pandas from a df table after using subscribe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

After using subscribe I get this table for example:

```
       sum  name
count  30      a
unique  5      b
```

I want to get for example the first value with is 30. How to do that?

```
nbl.describe(include=['object'])
```

Thank you!

Comment: ```df.loc['count','sum']``` ?

Comment: df.iloc[0]['sum'] helped me. thanks!